How to Retrieve PayPal Subscription Details Using Payer ID (User ID)?
I'm working on integrating PayPal subscriptions into my system, and I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to get all active subscription details for a user using the payer_id (also referred to as user_id).
In PayPal's User Management section, I can see there's an API to get user details, which includes information like the user's name, email, and address. However, I'm not able to find a way to retrieve any subscription details directly tied to the payer_id.
In my setup, when a user subscribes, they get assigned a payer_id, which I can retrieve using webhooks. I would like to know if there's a way to query PayPal for all subscriptions associated with that payer_id.
Is there any API in PayPal that allows fetching subscriptions by payer_id? Or is maintaining a mapping between payer_id and subscription_id in my own database the only approach?
Any guidance on how to achieve this or workarounds would be greatly appreciated!

There is no API to list subscriptions. PayPal expects you to track subscription statuses in your own database.
Subscribe to the webhook PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED and use it to update the good-through date of each event's subscription in your database.
If you need additional data for reconciliation, add a custom_id field when creating the subscription with whatever value you need.
